# wp multisite domain don't work

Tags: multisite

I installed wp and multisite (formacionemprendedores.com), I created three sites, I installed the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin. I configured the IP server, I have write evernotecertifiedconsultant.com reaches formacionemprendedores.com but will not your own site.

what append?

Comment: What does "wp" mean?

Comment: @NabilKadimi wordpress?

Comment: @kero Most likely.